# SwiftUI programatically create grid of letter tiles

Tags: grid, swiftui, tile

I am new to SwiftUI and have been looking at a way to create a word tile game.

I have a tileView, and my contentView adds a number of tiles.  My issue is I would like to programmatically build the tiles vertically as well as horizontally, in a grid. This makes me think that H-Stack and V-Stack are not appropriate for this use.

What I would like to do is:

1. The user taps on a tile
2. If the tile does not have a tile directly above, below or beside it it will present a new tile to fill those spaces. Hence the user can build the layout themselves.

Very naively I am assuming to do this I would check if there is a tileView a co-ordinate directly above the tile tapped. Then If the result is negative, I instantiate a tile in this new space.  But I am guessing as this is in 2 dimensions, it cannot be in a H-Stack or V-Stack.

Here is the start of my code. tileView is basically drawing a rectangle with the character on it. This iterates through the array and adds the tiles in HStack.  The issue here is this is for horizontal layout, not two dimensions. I am reading now that iOS 14 contains LazyVGrid and I am wondering if I could utilise this for what I want.
So the user selects any of these letters and directly above and below each tile appears another letter.

```
var str:[Character] = ["T", "E", "S", "T"]
    var body: some View {
    
        HStack {
            ForEach((str), id: \.self) { Character in
            tileView( letter: Character)
            }       
    }
```

If anyone has some pointers or suggested reading material I would appreciate it,  thanks.

Comment: You won't get much help without showing what you've tried so far.

Comment: Apologies, I haven't really got much to show, but I understand I need to show effort. I have updated with the start of my code and what I have read into.  I am not looking for someone to give me the answer, but just to advise me on which function or framework I should read into.

Comment: SO is not for recommendations. One of the reasons for closing a question is *Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more
This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers.* And your question falls exactly into this category.

Comment: Okay, so to develop this question then and where I have been.  I have investigated LazyVGrid and whilst I can look at making a grid of tiles, I do not believe I can reference their position or replace a cell in a LazyVGrid with a new one.  So I cannot use that.  My question is,  Is there a way to do what I want in SwiftUI?  Or should I go back to UIKit for this project?

Comment: Why can't you use LazyVGrid? While SwiftUI may not be fully developed yet, it looks like it has everything you need. I suggest you try with it and if you have specific questions come back and post another question.